# how to export talend job as single fat jar

Tags: talend

Is it possible to export the talend job as one jar only (inclusive of all its dependencies)?  Because currently, the exported zip file has the dependencies outside.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never found a way to achieve the one single jar inclusive of dependencies output via the Talend Open Studio (Community Edition).  The workaround is to create a Java Application, add the libraries and the job jars into it, then package that java application as one fat jar.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you did this please? It would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the job.

Repository > jobs > your job > right click > build job

Comment: I know.  But the output of that using 'Standalone job' option is: 2 folders (the job folder which has the jar file for the jar and the scripts, the lib folder which contains the dependencies).  I want the main jar file and the library dependencies included in only one jar.