# Is there any good way to integrate Talend job with Amazon EMR?

Tags: hadoop, talend, emr

Currently I'm trying to integrate AWS EMR with Talend.

My purpose is to run the Talend job ( exported by Talend studio ) on AWS EMR.  I already tried "add step as custom jar", but it seems Talend job run by using also exported `lib` folder and script.

I would like to run it with fat jar, however this question shows we can't do that because of lacking a feature to export JAR file as fat jar. --> [how to export talend job as single fat jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42662185/how-to-export-talend-job-as-single-fat-jar/42848320)

Is there any good way to integrate Talend job with Amazon EMR ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I resolved this problem by using `script-runner.jar` provided by AWS.

[Run a Script in a Cluster](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hadoop-script.html)

I created Lambda script to start EMR clusters. And I append `HadoopJarStep`. 
This allows us to use some shell scripts to download & kick the Talend job shell script.

- Please see [Boto3 Docs - EMR](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/emr.html) to know the meaning

  ```
          'HadoopJarStep': {
              'Jar': 's3://ap-northeast-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar',
              'Args': [
                  's3://your/bucket/name.../talend_run.sh'
              ]
          }
  ```

`talend_run.sh` is like below (a pity shellscript)

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Start, Talend!!"

# here is exported talend job ( contains bootstrap shellscript )
ZIP_NAME=talend-batch-zipped.zip
DIR_NAME=talend-batch-zipped/kicker
SHELL_NAME=kicker_run.sh

# update package because EMR servers don't have unzip command
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install -y wget unzip

rm -rf ${ZIP_NAME}
wget https://your.using.s3.host.name/${ZIP_NAME} -P `pwd`/

# unzip the zipped job file into the EMR server
unzip ${ZIP_NAME}
cd ${DIR_NAME}

# pass parameters to talend job
bash ./${SHELL_NAME} "$@"
```

After I started AWS Lambda function, the EMR cluster is created. After that, a step (above shell) processed by the EMR server.

Comment: Hi, Can you please, provide step by step instruction of what you did?

Comment: Did you still use the jar file exported from Talend? Maybe showing the content of the talend_run.sh script would help other users.

Comment: @ippomakunochi I'm no more using EMR. Because it's overkill for my current job.